# C# Excel.Chart The bar chart axis unit issue

Tags: c#, excel, charts

When making a Bar chart with percentage label, I am using this way.

```
Excel.DataLabel dl1 = (Excel.DataLabel)series.DataLabels(0);
dl1.NumberFormat = "0.00%;-0.00%;";
```

By putting this format, it would multyply 100 to input values. That is fine. But the problem is the Axis measure values show like:

[image]

How can I fix it? Or any other ways to add '%' to value labels?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to select the X axis of the chart and then change the format of the `TickLabels.NumberFormat` property:

```
    // Select the X axis
    var xAxis = (Axis)yourChart.Axes(XlAxisType.xlCategory, XlAxisGroup.xlPrimary);
    // Update the format of the tick labels
    xAxis.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%;";
```

Comment: Perfect answer except for probably a ";" needed, otherwise it seem not to work.
xAxis.TickLabels.NumberFormat = "0.00%;";

Comment: @Rich I've updated the answer to reflect so, glad I could help

Comment: Cool! Thanks,Chawin.